# WPF XBAP Custom Splash Screen

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, splash-screen, xbap

`SplashScreen` class ([.NET Framework 4.5 Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.SplashScreen.aspx)) says:

> The **SplashScreen** class cannot be used in **XAML Browser Applications (XBAPs)**, because they use a different startup architecture.

So i guess there is a need to provide some manual plumbing to change standard `XBAP` loading screen, looking for any information about this process.

Comment: I honestly don't think there's a way. As far as I recall, you have zero control over the XBAP cold start. Your best bet is to improve the startup time.

Comment: Startup time is not a real problem (whole application with dependent assemblies is like 1.5 mb and is loaded over LAN), the point is xbap is integrated in some information system and user doesn't need to know about the fact he is working in XBAP application at specific point of time. He doesn't see address bar nor have access to html's source, by removing/customizing xbap loader I will persuade him that needed functionality is the part of system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to change the load page of XBAP applications as the page is shown by PresentationHost.exe.

Anyway following links provide suggestions and possible workarounds

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/d252c7ca-2ff9-4e09-9459-fb34fe8c1eb5/

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/fffe2d9b-f512-40a4-84c3-756d690ea413/

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/c2779c8a-a58a-4b3e-b2c4-d056c754c999/

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/a58c20c8-cd2c-49b1-82ed-1e67df41436c

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/8445a222-969d-400a-864f-79c92a19fb04

Comment: Looked through your links and find out (the only?) possible way to solve the problem is hide application iframe during loading routine and/or provide some client-side loader in html. I'm pretty sure this approach will have much side-effects - now i'm invoking application's methods via BrowserHostScript interop javascript callbacks and not very satisfied with its smoothness.